# "Prepare for segue" for WatchKit

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, segue, watchkit

I am attempting to transfer a string from one view controller to another. The Problem that I having is that it is required to set the string 'as any object'.

The code I have below returns a nil in the console. Is there any way to send data across VC's as strings? Thanks in advance.

In MainVc-

```
func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String) -> AnyObject? {
    // You may want to set the context's identifier in Interface Builder and check it here to make sure you're returning data at the proper times

    // Return data to be accessed in ResultsController
    var currentValue = "Hellooo"
    return currentValue as String as AnyObject
}
```

In receiving VC.

```
override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)
    if let val: Any = context as? Any {
        print(val)
    } else {
        print("An error occurred")
    }        // Configure interface objects here.
}
```

The output is simply nil.

Comment: That's the method from the doc: `func contextForSegue(withIdentifier segueIdentifier: String) -> Any?` That's the one in Swift 3 while I think you are using the one in Swift 2, so I guess it's not even called. What make me think of that? There is a `AnyObject` and a `Any`, and `Any` have "replaced" `AnyObject` in Swift 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `currentValue as String` has no effect, `currentValue` is already a `String`.

Secondly, casting `val` to `Any` again makes no sense, since `val` is already of non-explicit type, `Any`. You should conditional cast it to `String`, since you are expecting a `String` variable.

For such a simple case, I wouldn't use 'contextForSegueWithIdentifier' at all, I would just simply use `presentController(withName:context:)` or `pushController(withName:context:)`.

Using these you don't need to do any casting, you can simply do `presentController(withName: "MyContoller", context: "Hello")`.

Comment: And how do your GET the context in the receiving view controller

Comment: The same way you do with a segue, in `awake(withContext:)`

Answer (score 1):

I came across with the same problem. The solution was as Larme suggested, used the appropriate function for swift 3 or 4, in this case, I assume you tried to use this code

override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String) -> AnyObject? {

but the compiler suggests that doesn't have to be overridden because Method does not override any method from its superclass

The easy solution is to remove the override. The app compiles but the contextForSegue function is never dispatched.

The correct structure is as follow:

override func contextForSegue(withIdentifier segueIdentifier: String) -> Any?
    {